# IRS API Tin Matching A2A flow - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: irs

I get an access token and a refresh token just fine. I know the access token is valid since trying to get a new access token using the refresh results in "Access token still has not expired". The scope shows as "tinm".
Anyone has a clue why I keep getting unauthorized?

Tried various formats, changing audience, validating token

Answer (score 0):

The consent approval needs to happen on the organization for TIN matching , not API eServices and use the user ID generated there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).